# Samsung Galaxy S, Front facing camera is not an option

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera, video, skype, video-calling

First off, I'm very very new to this. 
How do I activate my front facing camera in my Galaxy S? It's up to date on software according to the US Cellular store, I brought it in for an update not long ago

(I'm running hardware version I500.04, it's model number SCH-I500, firmware version 2.3.5, and kernel version 2.6.35.7, not sure what's necessary)

When the camera, skype, or YIM is open, there is no option to change camera display. I'm not sure what to do, because it appears to have a front facing camera installed. 
Does anyone have advice? I've looked around, but haven't been able to find an answer that truly answers my question.

So...how do I activate this camera? It's a large part of why I bought the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Open pre-installed Camera app & tap this icon to switch cam:
[image: Camera Switch]
Same icon is found in [Camera360 Ultimate](https://market.android.com/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360) (my fav) to switch cam.
Front-facing cam is automatically activated during video calls over 3G (if you are using pre-installed Dialer app).

Comment: I don't have that camera button, my menu stops at the fourth icon from the bottom. I'll check out that app though! thank you.

Comment: Then, its better to use `Camera360 Ultimate`. If you're rooted, you can upgrade inbuilt cam app from others APK.. I have Galaxy S too and that button is there.

Comment: Sachin, sir, I think you grossly overestimate my skill set. I'm trying to figure out how to root, but am running gingerbread (I think), so that involves a new version of it, and some form of program I don't quite understand. Do you have a suggested walkthrough? I'm googling to no avail- need a 'rooting for dummies' style instruction manual, aha. I'm entirely out of my depth here. Thank you though, I adore that Camera 360 Ultimate app already!

Comment: Worths a new question..

Answer (score 0):

On my S4 one day the icon for toggling between cameras simply disappeared.  After reading the above answer and the other replies not being of help , I just stated digging around. Sure enough what I cound was while in shoot mode I hit the menu button left of home and it listed only "change icons" or something like that. Up came a screen if icons one of which was the change-camera icon that had gone away! Just like any desktop icon, holding it down and dragging it to the location I wanted it in was the trick.